# Synonymize [pseudo-terminals] to [pty]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

Can we make [pseudo-terminals](/questions/tagged/pseudo-terminals) a synonym for [pty](/questions/tagged/pty)?

Comment: I think we should go the other way, with [tag:pseudo-terminals] the master tag. I'd have no idea what [tag:pty] meant without reading the wiki excerpt. It is not sufficiently self-evident, and three letter abbreviations can have too many other meanings.

Comment: @CodyGray I'd post that as an answer

Comment: @CodyGray Yes, that way might be wiser, although people who know about pseudo-terminals would probably know about the abbreviation, whereas people who don't know about pesudo-terminals would probably have to look them up anyway.

Comment: I know (vaguely) what a pseudo-terminal is, but I've never heard PTY before. Granted, I'm no expert. But I think the synonym system works fine for this; anyone who used [tag:pty] would still get what they wanted. Apparently @minitech disagrees with me about this.